# Unable to install python scipy in suse 11.3

Tags: python, scipy

I am unable to install scipy in Suse 11.3.

I followed the docs in this link:

[scipy installation](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html#id7)

I installed:

```
lapack
ATLAS
```

Then I git clone scipy and ran python setup.py install, I keep getting these errors. Is there any steps I missed?

```
/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 _import_umath(void)
 ^
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/cluster/_vq.o -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6 -llapack -lptf77blas -lptcblas -latlas -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/cluster/_vq.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libptf77blas.a(sgemm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib64/libptf77blas.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libptf77blas.a(sgemm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib64/libptf77blas.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/cluster/_vq.o -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6 -llapack -lptf77blas -lptcblas -latlas -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/cluster/_vq.so" failed with exit status 1
```

error when installing from git:

```
/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]

 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \

  ^

scipy/cluster/_vq.c: In function ‘__pyx_fuse_0__pyx_f_5scipy_7cluster_3_vq_cal_M’:

scipy/cluster/_vq.c:1538:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sgemm_’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

   f_sgemm(__pyx_k_T, __pyx_k_N, (&__pyx_v_ncodes), (&__pyx_v_nobs), (&__pyx_v_nfeat), (&__pyx_v_alpha), __pyx_v_code_book, (&__pyx_v_nfeat), __pyx_v_obs, (&__pyx_v_nfeat), (&__pyx_v_beta), __pyx_v_M, (&__pyx_v_ncodes));

   ^

scipy/cluster/_vq.c: In function ‘__pyx_fuse_1__pyx_f_5scipy_7cluster_3_vq_cal_M’:

scipy/cluster/_vq.c:1575:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dgemm_’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

   f_dgemm(__pyx_k_T, __pyx_k_N, (&__pyx_v_ncodes), (&__pyx_v_nobs), (&__pyx_v_nfeat), (&__pyx_v_alpha), __pyx_v_code_book, (&__pyx_v_nfeat), __pyx_v_obs, (&__pyx_v_nfeat), (&__pyx_v_beta), __pyx_v_M, (&__pyx_v_ncodes));

   ^

In file included from /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h:317:0,

                 from scipy/cluster/_vq.c:243:

scipy/cluster/_vq.c: At top level:

/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]

 _import_umath(void)

 ^

gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/cluster/_vq.o -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6 -llapack -lptf77blas -lptcblas -latlas -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/cluster/_vq.so

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libptf77blas.a(sgemm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/local/lib64/libptf77blas.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libptf77blas.a(sgemm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/local/lib64/libptf77blas.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: Command "gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/cluster/_vq.o -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6 -llapack -lptf77blas -lptcblas -latlas -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/cluster/_vq.so" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-5ylcSA-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-86Pqof-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-5ylcSA-build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Did you try https://www.google.com/search?q=collect2%3A+error%3A+ld+returned+1+exit+status&oq=collect2%3A+error%3A+ld+returned+1+exit+status&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 ?

Comment: @boardrider, yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with blas / ATLAS - the version you have installed and scipy is trying to link to has not been compiled with the `-fPIC` option.  This is indicated in the error message you see. [Here is a discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-October/058643.html) of the issue and its resolution - in summary you have a version with static libraries (`.a`) rather than shared libraries (`.so`).

Note from the [scipy install pages](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html#atlas) (their emphasis):

> **There is currently no comfortable way to use ATLAS on openSuse.**

It's up to you what you do - you can find a version suitable for installation on your system that has compiled with that option, you could [use BLAS + LAPACK](http://mybrainextension.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/installing-scipy-070-on-opensuse.html) instead of ATLAS, or you can compile ATLAS yourself.  Instructions on how to compile yourself [are here](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/atlas_install.html).  Specifics on adding the `-fPIC` option [are here](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node17.html).

It should be noted that the scipy docs tell you to use the `ashigabou` repositories, but the links are broken.  Google reveals [this repository](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:ashigabou).  The contents look old, but will allow you to follow the process on the page you linked exactly, I think.

---

I noticed that if you download ATLAS from its sourceforge page in a version > 3.9.4, you can see in the ChangeLog that the developers:

> - Added BETA support for auto-building shared/dynamic libraries when the
>     user passes --shared to configure (no need to explicitly set compiler
>     flags [eg., -fPIC] for any of the known compilers):
>
>   - Not fully tested, but appears to work for Windows, OS X and Linux
>   - Now referenced in make install, but present process is crude
>   - with --nof77, get clapack reather than lapack; eventually probably want
>       a logical link of lapack

i.e. you should be able to just pass `--shared` to configure the build as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
```

if you don't already have pip then go here:
[link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)

then run the pip install command.